# Triple or even quardruple? join - Mysql

Tags: mysql, join

Now this question  got me so bad i am even not sure about the question headline.

I have 4 tables (topic t, user u, entry e, user_fav u_f), respectively

```
topic_id  topic_name
   1         abba
   2         queen
   3         rolling stones

user_id    user_name 
   1          a             
   2          b      
   3          c 
   4          d


entry_id   entry   topic_fk(FK to t.topic_id)  user_fk(FK to u.user_id)
   1       .....              1                          1
   2       .....              1                          2
   3       .....              2                          2
   4       .....              2                          3
   5       .....              3                          4

user_fav_id  user_name  entry_fk(FK to e.entry_id)
   1            a                   1
   2            a                   2
   3            a                   3
   4            c                   4
   5            d                   5
```

and my question is how i can reach to `t.topic_name` using `u_f.user_name`?

An example to be more precise: if i want to use user `a`,

i need to get `u_f.entry_fk` (which are 1, 2 & 3)

then i need to get `e.topic_fk`(which are 1, 1 & 2)

and finally, i need to get `t.topic_name` (which are abba, abba & queen) (pay attention i need 2 `abba`'s with different `entry_id`s with them)

Comment: what have you try so far ? Are you familiar with left Join ?

Comment: i can not even think anything.

Answer (score -1):

You can use sql [joins](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/). Try this:

```
SELECT t.topic_name, e.entry_id
FROM `user` u 
LEFT JOIN entry e ON u.user_id=e.user_id
INNER JOIN topic t ON e.topic_id=t.topic_id
WHERE u.user_name='a';
```

Comment: i also need `entry_id`s

Comment: @kai I just included it. Please click the link in the answer for insights on sql joins.